# How to retrieve Categories name and children ? Magento

Tags: magento, model

I would like to retrieve the categories of my website in order to build me own Category menu.
but I don't understand how to get all the categories from the class/model. So I've created a file called top.phtml that I've put in template/catalog/navigation ,

First, do I MUST put that name to the file into that folder if I want to create a top Menu ? Can t I decide where to put it with the name I want like TopMenu.phtml ? Because in evry tut I red, they are doing the same way ..

Second : What i the function I must call ? I've been here : http://www.magentix.fr/ergonomie-web/agencer-page-accueil-site-magento.html but the way the do that doesn t work for me .. I add that code to my file top.phtml properly called in the page.xml :

```
<div class="category-list" style="background-color:white;">
<h2>Nos produits</h2>
<?php
    foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category):
            if($_category->getIsActive()):
                    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
                    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory($_category);
                    ?>        
                         <div class="category-list-view">
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName()?>">
                                       <img src="<?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>" />
                                </a>
                                <h3><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>" class="name" title="<?php echo $_category->getName()?>"><?php echo $_category->getName()?></a></h3>
                         </div>
                    <?php
            endif;
    endforeach;
?> 
</div>
```

Last : where could I find a clear user guide like there is for CodeIgniter ? I found that, but I never found any answer on it : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api#magento_core_api

Thanks for your answers, I m a web dev used to work with CodeIgniter or without any template, and I can t clearly see the logic behind Magento way of programming.

EDIT: Is there anything to do with the categories ? Becaue I tried to  create a sub category under the Default Category and it do work, but if I create a new Root Category,It simply didnt recognize it .. why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, do I MUST put that name to the file into that folder if I want to create a top Menu ? Can t I decide where to put it with the name I want like TopMenu.phtml ? Because in evry tut I red, they are doing the same way ..

You can name your template file whatever you like. However, it's best to follow the nomenclature and established conventions. The template filename is contingent on your layout XML. It should have the `template` attribute, something like `<block name="x" type="x/y" template="catalog/navigation/topmenu.phtml" />` (for example).

> Second : What i the function I must call ? I've been here : http://www.magentix.fr/ergonomie-web/agencer-page-accueil-site-magento.html but the way the do that doesn t work for me

The functions available to your template (`topmenu.phtml` file) depend on the block's type. In your layout XML, you should specify the block type that corresponds to the functionality you need. In your case, you're probably looking for the block type to be `catalog/navigation`. If you look in `./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`, you can see what public methods are available to your template. Several of the methods here facilitate generating (nested) category listing. This is where your `getStoreCategories()` method comes from. Remember that these blocks inherit from several parenting classes, so you have a lot more methods available than you may at first think.

> where could I find a clear user guide like there is for CodeIgniter ? I found that, but I never found any answer on it : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api#magento_core_api

That's a link to the Magento API. What you need is a tutorial on Magento layout XML and the design layer therein. The Magento wiki has some good info, but Google around and you'll find a ton of really helpful resources on understanding Magento's design system.

> Is there anything to do with the categories ? Becaue I tried to create a sub category under the Default Category and it do work, but if I create a new Root Category,It simply didnt recognize it .. why

A root category is what you'll use to identify the basis of the catalog for the selected store(s). You will never see the root category appear on the frontend (and you shouldn't). Each subcategory within the root category is the top-level category; sub-categories beneath those subcategories (tertiary categories) would appear as your "second-level" categories on the Magento frontend. You might want to look into Magento's GWS ("global, website, store") scope system, and how it manages catalog data in a multi-store setup to better understand why root categories function this way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great Job Jona, Thanks ! Very Helpful !